# multiple entity type in entity field query

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

How to add multiple entity_type and bundles in `EntityFieldQuery`?

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'profile2')
       ->entityCondition('bundle', 'user_profile');
```

Is there any way to do like this?

```
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', array('profile2','user'))
       ->entityCondition('bundle', array('user_profile','property'));
```

Comment: Did you even try? According to the documentation it supposed to work just like that.

Comment: it works with single entity type.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7

> This class allows finding entities based on entity properties (for example, node->changed), field values, and generic entity meta data (bundle, entity type, entity id, and revision ID). **It is not possible to query across multiple entity types.** For example, there is no facility to find published nodes written by users created in the last hour, as this would require querying both node->status and user->created.

Answer (score 2):

In the official [doc](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!entity.inc/function/EntityFieldQuery%3A%3AentityCondition/7):

```
public EntityFieldQuery::entityCondition($name, $value, $operator = NULL)
```

where:

**$name**: 'entity_type', '**bundle**', 'revision_id' or 'entity_id'.

**$value**: The value for $name. In most cases, this is a scalar. For more complex options, it is an **array**. The meaning of each element in **the array is dependent on $operator**.

**$operator**: Possible values:

```
'=', '<>', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'STARTS_WITH', 'CONTAINS': These operators expect $value to be a literal of the same type as the column.
'IN', 'NOT IN': These operators expect $value to be an array of literals of the same type as the column.
'BETWEEN': This operator expects $value to be an array of two literals of the same type as the column.
```

**I guess you forgot the operator!**

Comment: Does it solve your problem? If yes, don't forget to mark this answer as the good answer to close the topic.